# Using Flask cannot delete register from table in a many-to-one relationship (unable to delete from many side)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=True)
created_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
updated_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)

tokens = db.relationship('TokenModel', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
# datasets = db.relationship('DatasetModel', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
ml_models = db.relationship('MlModelModel', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
ml_model_computations = db.relationship('MlModelComputationModel', backref='user', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class DatasetModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'datasets'
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
description = db.Column(db.Text)
origin_link = db.Column(db.Text)
min_row = db.Column(db.Integer)
max_row = db.Column(db.Integer)
min_column = db.Column(db.Integer)
max_column = db.Column(db.Integer)
labels = db.Column(db.JSON)
# is_anonymized = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
anonymous_labels = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False)
image_length = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1000)
image_height = db.Column(db.Integer, default=11)
status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
created_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
updated_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)


medias = db.relationship('MediaModel', backref='dataset', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
ml_models = db.relationship('MlModelModel', backref='dataset', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
ml_model_computations = db.relationship('MlModelComputationModel', backref='dataset', lazy=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')
user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
user = db.relationship('UserModel', backref='datasets', lazy=True)

def delete(self, dataset_id):
    user = UserModel.get_by_id(get_jwt()["sub"])
    if user:
        dataset = DatasetModel.query.get_or_404(dataset_id)

        if dataset.user_id != user.id:
            return jsonify({"message": "Invalid user."}), 401

        raised_exception = False
        try:
            db.session.execute("DELETE FROM datasets WHERE id = :id", {"id": dataset.id})
            # db.session.delete(dataset)
            db.session.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            raised_exception = True
        finally:
            if raised_exception:
                return jsonify({"message": "An error occurred while deleting the dataset."}), 500
            else:
                if FILE_HELPER.directory_exists(DATASETS_DATA_STORAGE + "/" + str(dataset.id)):
                    raised_exception = False
                    try:
                        FILE_HELPER.remove_directory(DATASETS_DATA_STORAGE + "/" + str(dataset.id))
                    except FileExistsError as e:
                        raised_exception = True
                    finally:
                        return {"message": "Dataset deleted."}, 200
                else:
                    return {"message": "Dataset deleted, but dir not found."}, 200
```

As a last attempt to delete a row from datasets table I try to execute a SQL query directly to the database, but with no positive results (deletion of row). I got SQLALCHEMY_ECHO as true, so the output is the following:

```
web-1     | 2024-02-29 16:32:41,588 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password, users.created_at AS users_created_at, users.updated_at AS users_updated_at 
web-1     | FROM users 
web-1     | WHERE users.id = %s 
web-1     |  LIMIT %s
web-1     | 2024-02-29 16:32:41,589 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00144s] (1, 1)
web-1     | 2024-02-29 16:32:41,603 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT datasets.id AS datasets_id, datasets.name AS datasets_name, datasets.description AS datasets_description, datasets.origin_link AS datasets_origin_link, datasets.min_row AS datasets_min_row, datasets.max_row AS datasets_max_row, datasets.min_column AS datasets_min_column, datasets.max_column AS datasets_max_column, datasets.labels AS datasets_labels, datasets.anonymous_labels AS datasets_anonymous_labels, datasets.image_length AS datasets_image_length, datasets.image_height AS datasets_image_height, datasets.status AS datasets_status, datasets.created_at AS datasets_created_at, datasets.updated_at AS datasets_updated_at, datasets.user_id AS datasets_user_id 
web-1     | FROM datasets 
web-1     | WHERE datasets.id = %s
web-1     | 2024-02-29 16:32:41,605 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00152s] (1,)
web-1     | 2024-02-29 16:32:41,610 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
web-1     | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2024:16:32:41 +0000] 'DELETE /datasets/1 HTTP/1.1' 200 55 '-' 'insomnia/8.6.0' in 132702µs
```

It seems like the delete query to the database did never run, but apparently the ROLLBACK command did.
I want to delete a dataset using its own model or id but i cannot any help is appreciated.

Comment: `from src.extensions import db

from config.settings import DATASETS_DATA_STORAGE, DEBUG                                           instead of                                                                                                                                            from src.extensions import db

from config.settings import *`